# useEffect runs prior to rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
export default function Example() {

   useEffect(()=>{
       console.log('DOM has not rendered anything yet')
   });

    return (
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    );
}
```

What am I getting with the above code is the console message first and then `Hello` appears on my page. However, by debugging the code I can see `return` precedes `useEffect`. Why then Hello is not visible when `useEffect` runs for the first time?

[image]

Moreover, if using the code from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks:

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

seeing that when callback of useEffect is being executed for the first time, only the button is visible not `You clicked 0 times`.

Comment: `useEffect` and the callback passed to it are two different things.

Comment: What do you mean console is printed before hello is shown? Can you actually see the one millisecond between the 2 things happening? I put a `debugger` in the effect and I can see hello printed in the dom when the effect executes so even if you have millisecond fast eyesight the debugger proves you wrong.

Comment: By debugging the code I can see the page is empty when the callback is executed.

Comment: No, it is not. Not with the code you  provided. I can see hello in the dom when the debugger pauses in the effect.

Comment: Hey, it's 2023 and I ran into this exact issue. My `useEffect` is running but the component has not yet finished dom manipulations. I can prove it by having a `ref` on a `div`. The `ref.current` points to the `div`, but the `div` is not yet added to the document when `useEffect` runs. Have you find any good answer to your issue back then?

Answer (score 0):

See the hooks-effect [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)

> **What does useEffect do?** By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something **after render**. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and **call it later after performing the DOM updates**. In this effect, we set the document title, but we could also perform data fetching or call some other imperative API.

Comment: You do not answer my question. Why the callback of useEffect runs whereas `Hello` is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code and see the order of the log messages.

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('DOM has not rendered anything yet')
  });

  function hello() {
    console.log("render")
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={hello()} >
      Hello
    </div>
  );

}
```

useEffect is like componentDidMount in that it runs after the first render and after each update to the dom.

The code above demonstrates that render is called first followed by useEffect.

Comment: My question is very simple but it seems everyone misunderstood it: Why `Hello` is not visible when the callback of useEffect runs? Is there any good explanation for that?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper there must be latency on your system that makes it seem that hello was not painted to the screen. Is that what's happening? Your callback is called before you can see `Hello` on the screen? In reality, useEffect can only run after the screen has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, you can open the devtools and see that hello is rendered when the debugger statement pauses your code. This is how React behaves as documented and as 2 people already pointed out.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    console.log('last');
  });
  console.log('first');
  //this is returned and react will render this to dom before
  //  your effect is called as documented and as 2 people already pointed out
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the picture please.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper How is Example rendered? Could it be in a hidden component? Maybe right click the DOM and inspect it or check out element tab to see what the DOM is.

Comment: Absolutely normally. Did you try the code from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks ?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper If it's a problem with your browser then the code above should have the same problem, maybe it's how App is rendered and how App renders Example. I am trying to create a snippet that reproduces what you experience but with code you provided (code above) I cannot reproduce it using my browser (Chrome)

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper You are not using any experimental react features are you? Like [concurrent](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html)

Comment: I have just tried Firefox and not getting this strange behaviour...

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Just curious, what browser were you using that created this strange behavior?

Comment: Chrome 80.0.3987.122